# AJAX not functioning

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mongodb

I have been staring at this for literally two hours trying to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. For some reason the table isn't being loaded when the button is clicked.

Here's the relevant part of my head:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
</head>
```

This is my table:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="midtxt">
        <div id = "transactions-sav" style="margin-top: 0;">
            <h2>Most Recent Transactions</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Time & Date</th>
                        <th>Account Type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <div id="trans-div">
                    </div>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn light-blue waves-effect waves-light table-end" id="trans-more" style="margin-top: 35px;">Load More Transactions</a>
    </div>
```

This is my Ajax transmitter:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let transCount = 20;
        $('#trans-more').on('click', function() {
            transCount += 20;
            console.log('click');
            console.log(transCount);
            $('#trans-div').load('includes/loadtranshistajax.inc.php', {transNewCount: transCount,user_id: <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>}, function() {
                console.log('callback');
            });
        });
        console.log('test1');
    });
</script>
```

This is my PHP script for generating the table. It is worth noting that initialize() starts a session.:

```
   <?php
require_once 'dbc-stu.inc.php';
require_once 'initialize.inc.php';
require_once 'app/transactions/transhist.inc.php';
initialize();
initialize_secure();

//Import the count
$limit = $_POST['transNewCount'];
$userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE trans_targetID ='$userID' ORDER BY trans_time DESC LIMIT $limit";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'trans_time') {
            $time = $value;
            date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
            $time = date("F j, Y, g:i a",$time);
        } elseif ($key === 'trans_amount') {
            $amnt = $value;
        } elseif ($key ==='trans_targetID') {
            $username = idToUsername($value);
        } elseif ($key === 'trans_accType') {
            $accType = $value;
        }
    }
    echo '<td>' . $username . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $amnt . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $time . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $accType . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Edit, thanks a lot everybody. I'm fairly new to the web development community, so it's cool to see everyone help out!

Comment: Can you please check the network tab for AJAX request is triggered or not?

Comment: Where are you loading jQuery library?

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy I'm loading the the jQuery right above this script. From what I can tell in the XHR tab of the chrome dev console no AJAX requests are being sent.

Comment: Silly question but are you clicking the `#trans-more` element? If so, do you see the "click" message in your console?

Comment: @Phil Upon clicking the trans-more button click does appear.

Comment: @CaJamesia and you're absolutely sure there's no AJAX request being made? Make sure you're looking in the _Network_ tab of the dev console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove div  tag from  tag and add id in tbody attribute as below.

```
 <tbody id="trans-div"></tbody>
```

Comment: Good advice but I doubt this is the current problem. OP says they don't see the AJAX request firing at all

Comment: No As you can see the problem its inside tbody we are using div that is not good practice and table will not create according that.

Comment: Yes, but that would happen **after** the AJAX request which OP says isn't happening

Comment: CaJamesia i have run this and its working fine if you still facing a problem let me know i can create fiddle for you.If its working fine please mark this as accept.

Comment: @SINGH I did this, AJAX requests now showing in console, still not displaying table info

Comment: @phil if you will see the html in question which is <tbody> <div id="trans-div"> </div></tbody> then you will see that we should not use div inside table direct we can us it inside td if we want.

Comment: @SINGH you're really not following what I'm saying. Anyway, looks like you solved it :)

Comment: @CaJamesia have you remove div from tbody tag.

Comment: Disregard, this now worked, the AJAX requests are going through, I just forgot to import my common functions after changing the target. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @CaJamesia so your problem had absolutely nothing to do with the code in your question?

Comment: @Phil No, switching to the tbody instead of the div fixed it. I just had to do one more tweak then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Put the php code`<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>` inside a `<script>` tag into double quote as it's causing the `SyntaxError` which break` your script code.

That's why you are not able to view XHR into console

Try the following:

```
$('#trans-div').load('includes/loadtranshistajax.inc.php', {transNewCount: transCount,user_id: "<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>"}, function() {
    console.log('callback');
});
```